# Answer was upvoted, accepted, bountied... and wrong

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/8960/2509) was upvoted, accepted, bountied... and upon arriving at the destination, turned out to be factually incorrect.

I have undone the acceptance and added my own answer. However, I cannot undo my upvote and I think it also doesn't deserve the bounty.

What should be done in this situation?

**Update**: The answer in question has since been deleted and is therefore only visible to people with access to moderator tools.

Comment: Which answer are you talking about? I can only see one from you ...

Comment: @MarcelC. The answer has since been deleted. I've adapted the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well bounties can't be undone, so that one will sadly be a lost cause. (Unless there's a way I'm unaware of).

*(cough dirty weasel-hack)* If you edit the answer, make a cosmetic change and hit save, you'll then (for a short while) be able to change your upvote to either remove it or downvote instead.

Comment: You don't event have to make any change in the edit.