# What to do if an answer is false?

Tags: discussion, editing

A question was asked, and [an answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/109184/85359) was provided.  It has 60 upvotes, when no other answer has a score of 0 or higher.  However, this answer is false, and if the OP follows this advice, they are very likely to get into legal trouble.  I got charged with misrepresentation for following this exact advice.  Should I upload a PDF of my charge, as proof?  Or is anecdotal evidence from others also charged with misrepresentation enough?

Also, what is the appropriate course of action here?  Should I leave a comment, flag this post, and/or edit this answer to add something similar to "THIS ANSWER IS FALSE: see comment below" at the top?

Same exact answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/120810/85359).

Comment: As a first step why not post a comment similar to the one you posted on the second question/answer and see if the poster of the highly rated answer reacts?

Comment: Downvote and post your own answer.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks!  The poster modified their answer to say that this doesn't answer the original question, but outlined the types of cases where this answer would apply: so this would avoid giving people advice to do something with legal repercussions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Answer was upvoted, accepted, bountied... and wrong](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/answer-was-upvoted-accepted-bountied-and-wrong)

Answer (score 12):

Don't flag. It's not up to the mods to decide if it's correct or not - we can't be experts in everything and know the 'truth'.

Step 1 - downvote.

Step 2 - COMMENT. ALWAYS COMMENT IF YOU DOWNVOTE. Explain (politely) why it's wrong.

Step 3 - add your own answer, explain why it's correct, with evidence, and watch the votes flow in (hopefully).

Comment: "Always comment if you downvote": this is certainly good etiquette, but it is not Stack Exchange policy unless something has changed.  It is also within the bounds of good etiquette to upvote a comment that explains your downvote, if there is one, instead of posting a new comment.

Comment: @phoog of course, if a preexisting one covers it.  It's just frustrating to see an answer/question on -4 and with no comments whatsoever.

Comment: I agree completely.  I wish there were stricter requirements around this.  If an answer is downvoted without comment I usually post a comment either suggesting why I think the answer was voted down, if I can think of a possible reason, or asking why the answer was downvoted in the hope that someone will explain.